# удалить дубликаты в векторе

Tags: java, vector

Как удалить повторяющейся элементы в векторе ?

```
public static Vector<String> dublicate = new Vector<String>(1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте на его основе HashSet. Или, если важно сохранить порядок элементов, LinkedHashSet.

```
Set<String> unique = new LinkedHashSet<>(dublicate);
```